# Replace lowercase ASCII characters with X in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

What is the cleanest, most Pythonic code for replacing lowercase characters with 'X' in a string? For example, `ABCDEFGhijklmnopQRSTUVwxyz` would become `ABCDEFGXXXXXXXXXQRSTUVXXXX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy:

```
>>> import re
>>> S='ABCDEFGhijklmnopQRSTUVwxyz'
>>> re.sub('[a-z]', 'X', S)
'ABCDEFGXXXXXXXXXQRSTUVXXXX'
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for that; easily the fastest method. A regular expression cannot touch this for speed.

Python 2 version:

```
import string

map = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, 'X' * len(string.ascii_lowercase))
mapped = inputstring.translate(map)
```

Python 3 version:

```
import string

map = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 'X'))
mapped = inputstring.translate(map)
```

Demo (Python 2):

```
>>> import string
>>> inputstring = 'ABCDEFGhijklmnopQRSTUVwxyz'
>>> map = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, 'X' * len(string.ascii_lowercase))
>>> inputstring.translate(map)
'ABCDEFGXXXXXXXXXQRSTUVXXXX'
```

`str.translate()` is *orders of magniture* faster here:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import re
>>> def regex_replace(s, _sub=re.compile(r'[a-z]').sub):
...     return _sub('X', s)
... 
>>> regex_replace(inputstring)
'ABCDEFGXXXXXXXXXQRSTUVXXXX'
>>> timeit.timeit('f(s)', 'from __main__ import regex_replace as f, inputstring as s')
2.6076979637145996
>>> timeit.timeit('s.translate(m)', 'from __main__ import inputstring as s, map as m')
0.13378620147705078
```

The `str.translate()` version manages to do the task *20 times* faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
import re
output = re.sub( r'[a-z]', 'X', inputString )
```